# Unexpected results printing array of int pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I have a simple C program which uses a varying number of pthreads to find the first N prime numbers, adding candidates found to be prime to an array. The array is passed as an arg to each thread, with each thread executing nearly all of its code in a critical section. I have no issue with the prime checking, and the printing to screen of prime numbers and the result_number variable as they are found works. However, when N primes are found, and the array is printed, I find that (roughly) every second time the program executes, some (variably from 1 to 5) of the early prime number array elements (generally restricted to those < 17) are printed out as extremely large or negative numbers, with the majority of primes printing fine. Only the code of the thread function is below (not checkPrime or main), as everything else *seems* to work fine.

Also, if the program is executed with a single thread (i.e. no sharing of the array between multiple threads for updating), this peculiarity never occurs.

result_number, candidate, N are all global vars.

```
void *primeNums(void *arg) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    int *array = (int *) arg;
    int is_prime = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (result_number <= N) {

        candidate++;
        is_prime = checkPrime(candidate);

        if (is_prime == 1) {
            array[result_number] = candidate;
            if (result_number == N) {
                while (j < N) {
                    printf("%d\n", array[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            /* Test verification output; always accurate */
            printf("Result number: %d = %d\n", result_number, candidate);
            result_number++;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

I genuinely do not believe other Qs cover this, as I have looked (and would have preferred finding an answer to writing my own question). There is a chance that I am not searching properly, admittedly.

EDIT: Example unwanted output:
-386877696
3
-395270400
32605
11
13
...

Continues on fine from here.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that they would (most likely) be applicable, no?

Comment: Why does your function take a void pointer?

Comment: @Neil - It's executed as (that may not be the way to say it) a pthread, and it is my understanding (from all examples I've seen and from what I've read) that this is how it is done.

Comment: Are you manipulating the globals without taking the mutex?
Are you initializing the array to zeros?

Comment: Fair enough. Shouldn't your function return something?

Comment: @Rich - No, sir. The only manipulation of them is in this code block, which *I believe* is properly written to ensure they are not touched outside of the mutex.

Comment: @Neil - Ultimately, it will, a simple exit code (0 or 1). I've had that coded without problem as well, but started stripping away code to figure out what is causing this specific array-related issue.

Comment: Just a wild guess: There could be something wrong with your mutex. What you are observing would be consistent with *several* of your threads being in the critical section at the same time (the probability of a clash is much higher for the first few prime numbers, because they are calculated faster). What I don't understand is what you actually want: Almost the whole function is protected by a mutex, so (if it works), the first thread entering the critical section will do all the work. Then it frees the mutex, then there is nothing left for the other threads to do...

Comment: is `checkPrime()` re-entrant/accessed elsewhere without mutex?

Comment: The only thing beyond the mutex & initialization is the possibility that another thread is messing with your array.  Something very odd going on elsewhere.

Comment: @Galik - No, sir, it is not.

Comment: The reentrant safe checkPrime shouldn't matter - it has no idea the array exists.

Comment: If a function that returns a value reaches the end without a return statement, technically it is undefined behavior.

Comment: It would be great to have a full working example that shows the undefined behaviour. You should also check the initializations of `candidate`, `result_number` etc...

Comment: @carofthecdr: what is the point of using threads if all the work is done while holding a shared mutex?  Surely this doesn't achieve any real parallelism?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Exactly my thinking (see above).

Comment: Does `result_number` or `N` (or both) change for each thread?

Comment: @Neil - I've butchered this code and stripped it down to figure out this issue... but I agree with your point.

Comment: @John - I placed all of the code into one mutex to try and isolate the cause of the issue. Originally I had 2 separate critical sections, but perhaps this wasn't well-constructed either.

Comment: @Oguk - I think posting up more of the code may be more useful. It's an assignment though, so I will have to strip stuff away. I hoped I could avoid it, but ultimately it's probably the best idea.

Comment: @Galik - result_number would change for each thread (this is my intent, anyhow), but N does not. N is number of primes to test for.

Comment: Can you show us how you are launching these threads. I think your use of globals for the work range is problematic. You should really make those local.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm actually cobbling together the code to post up ASAP. Since it's an assignment, and it takes into account other tasks, I need to trim it down to bare essentials or violate policy.

Comment: I have a hunch that if, instead of passing in `array` and using the global `result_number`, you pass in `array + result_number` and loop on a local variable: `i = 0; while(i < N) {...}`, you may solve your problem. (assuming `array + result_number + N - 1` doesn't go out of bounds).

Comment: Ah you still have `candidate`. Then also you could try taking a local copy of `candidate` inside the lock. Better create a `struct` to contain your globals and pass the struct in rather than just the array.

Comment: @Galik - Thank you for the continued interest. As I've been poking around in the code to try to get something to post, it appears that some other things don't behave properly as I shift stuff around... I think you are on to something with your last couple of comments. I am going to re-do this and see how it turns out, and will post up progress tomorrow. Many thanks.

Comment: @Galik - If you add either of your last 2 comments (or both) as an answer, I will accept it as such. After rewriting the code with your suggestions in mind, the problem has disappeared. I am unsure of the exact mechanism as to why, yet it is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that if, instead of passing in array and using the global result_number, you pass in array + result_number and loop on a local variable: `i = 0; while(i < N) {...}`, you may solve your problem. (assuming `array + result_number + N - 1` doesn't go out of bounds).

The problem with using global variables to hold the range information for each thread is that the thread function `primeNums()` modifies some of them. So if you start your first thread (thread #1) with `result_number` set to the start of the range you want thread #1 to process, thread #1 will keep changing its value while you reset it to give to thread #2. So thread #2 won't be processing the range you want it to process.

I assume you want each thread to process a separate range of indexes in your array? Currently you are passing a pointer to the beginning of the array to the function and using a global variable to hold the index into the array of the chunk you want to have processed by that thread.

To avoid using that global index all you have to do is pass a pointer to an offset into the middle of your array where you want processing to begin. So rather than pass in the value that points to the beginning element (`array`) pass in a value that points to the element you want to start processing from (`array + result_number`).

If you do that, inside your function `primeNums()` it acts as if the pointer you passed in is the beginning of an array (even though its somewhere in the middle) and you can run your loop from `0` to `N` because you have already added `result_number` before you called the function.

Having said all that I suspect you are still not going to be able to process this array in parallel (if that's is indeed what you are trying to do) because each thread relies on the `candidate` being set to the largest value from the previous thread...

To protect 'candidate` from being simultaneously changed by the code that launches the other threads (if you do that) you can take a copy of that variable after you synchronize on your mutex (lock). But, to be honest, I am not sure if this algorithm is going to let you parallelise this processing.